# Is there a way of keeping a SSE connection but not run any code?

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

So basically I'm working with a server in PHP and client in JS and I need to implement a way of sending updates to clients.

There's a long polling that we want to replace for something more efficent so we were thinking in SSE but I want to send the data to a specific client after I do an INSERT into the database in a specific action.

So I have some questions about it

- Do I need to connect the EventSource from the client to the action that makes the INSERT to have access to it from there?
- It is possible to connect the EventSource to some action and not run the code in it?

Because I'll like to have the connection available to send data after the INSERT but I don't want to run the code every time the EventSource reconnect. Is any of this possible or should I use some other technology like WebSocket?

Thanks and sorry if my english sucks. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: In short: 1) No, not necessarily, and 2) No, there needs to be _something_ running PHP to keep the connection open, even if it's just a loop not doing much most of the time. Maybe websockets might suit you better, perhaps.

Comment: I try to not link to paid solutions too often, but I found [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) to be a great way to do exactly this with not a lot of code on either the client or the server. Their free tier gets you a lot of messages, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSE connection in PHP is a dedicated process (for each client). There has to be code there, but in your case it will be as simple as hanging around waiting for a signal that the INSERT has happened.

This is all likely to be identical to how your current long poll solution works?

> There's a long polling that we want to replace for something more efficent
> ...
> should I use some other technology like WebSocket?

It depends on in what way long poll is inefficient, but I'd expect the bottlenecks to not change.

SSE is really just a HTML5 standard, wrapped around how long poll works. And WebSocket is the same, except it is two-way (and trading more flexiblity for more complexity). In all three cases you are keeping a dedicated socket open (*), and there has to be a process on the server handling that connection.

*: Less of an issue with http2 multiplexing.